# How do I write an iPhone/iPad app to take care of different screen sizes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

With the new iPad (which has a different screen resolution of the iPhone/iPod Touch), how do I set the application to automatically size appropriately to the desired screen size?

Comment: It's a valid way of using the site.  Rather than posting "This is how to...", you are encouraged to share knowledge by asking, and then answering a question.  Look at the last sentence of the first question at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Also, it goes into detail on the other FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stack-overflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not - it comes down to building information that's useful to the community and is in one place. For this piece, it was a way of conveying information that's currently under NDA but without violating the NDA (since I've not downloaded the new SDK myself). Therefore, this will be useful to those wishing to know in the future. It doesn't mean I have to accept my own answer - as you note, the NDA is upvoted more than mine anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/index.html) in the 3.2 SDK beta documentation. It will tell you everything you need. The NDA means we can't talk about it here publically.

Answer (score 1):

Although the iPad SDK is still under NDA at this time, the iPhone SDK which preceeds it introduced the ability to change the screen size:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)opts
{
  UIScreen *s = [UIScreen mainScreen];    // ask for the main screen
  [window setFrame:[s applicationFrame]]; // get the application Frame for the screen
  return YES;
}
```

If you have used NIBs for the UI construction, you need to ensure that they're auto-resizable in order for them to flow properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in the code. It is in the project conversion from iPhone to iPad: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/4108